# Storing data for use on Android and Windows Applications

Tags: c#, android, xml, sqlite, cross-platform

thanks for taking a look at my question.

I'm developing a project proposal for my final year project at University and as I aim to use programming languages I am currently not too familiar with I'm looking for some guidance - I can't include details of my project but hopefully you will understand what I'm after.

I'm going to be creating an Android application (in Java) and a Windows Application (in C#) that will ideally access, query and update a remotely hosted Database or set of XML files (this would most likely be over the Internet).

I've done some looking around the internet and SQLite seems like a safe-bet for cross-platform manipulation of the database; however I would like to keep the system as lightweight as possible and I'm wondering whether XML files may provide a better alternative? Anyone out there that has experience using SQLite and/or remotely hosted XML for the purposes of Android and/or C# development that could point me in the right direction?

If there is an alternative solution other than those I have mentioned I would be interested to hear about them too.

Thank you for taking the time to read my question.

Edit: The purpose of this application is for a small scale business, the data source would not need to be updated by more than one source but may be view from multiple sources (i.e. through multiple phones and a desktop PC). The database wouldn't be updating masses of data at a time (most likely single rows of a few tables at the most).

Comment: Although you've put together a detailed question it isn't really suitable for stackoverflow. The idea of stackoverflow is to solve direct problems with existing code rather than generic discussion of "the best way" to do something. Try the [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) stackexchange site. In saying that, however, one piece of advice I'll give you is that concentrating too much on the client/server implementations is going to be the biggest hurdle you need to get over. By that I mean that it doesn't matter what your client platform is, it doesn't matter what your server pl

Comment: Ah, I'll copy-paste this question over to StackExchange then, thank you for the advice, it seems your reply was cut-off slightly though. Cheers for the answer :)
Andy

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a client/server architecture.

- Server: Unix + mysql database + xml based Java EE webservice
- Client 1: Android accessing a web service
- Client 2: c# accessing a web service

Comment: I'll make a note of these and do some research. Thanks for the guidance.